# Android: How to align images depending on size of another image? (Controller consisting of 4 buttons)

Tags: android, layout

I have 4 image buttons which should be aligned like this:

[image: Controller]

As you can see they overlap, so I can't use a simple table layout, because of "collapsing" table rows. My attempt was to use transparent images among those image buttons while I used nested and overlapping LinearLayouts to align them. With this attempt I don't have to worry about density related calculations. This seemed to work in the first place, but unfortunately one of the invisible buttons overlays the real image buttons, so I can't click at least one image button anymore, because it's like clicking the invisible button, overlaying the real image button.
Another difficulty is that I can't use density related alignments within the xml file. The reason is that these image buttons are scaled in a different way than other scaled images. This is because these image buttons should always be as big as a thumbnail despite of a phone or a tablet. So the usual alignment with margin is not applicable here.

I think the only way to achieve this is to calculate it programmatically. Or any other ideas?

Comment: What I would do is: In a **RelativeLayout**, make a centered image (`centerInParent="true"` and `visibility="invisible"`!!). Then set other 4 images aligned to its left, top, right, and bottom. And that's it. **NO NEED** to do that programmatically. And you **don't need to mess with LinearLayouts** at all. Keep the scaling using **dp** as you measure unit

Comment: I already tried out something similar (except that the central view was visible too).

Comment: I tinkered something based on your tip. See my answer.

Comment: Well, the central (invisible) one should be declared BEFORE all others, in order to be referenced by those ones. And you sholdn't need the button_invisible_top_left (it's one more View which only purpose is to act as a space waster)

Comment: Yes it works. Ok, I don't know if I placed it before all others (but I don't think so). Probably that's why I had strange behaviour. Moreover centerInParent="true" caused the visible button's edges to border on the center of the invisible image placed in the center and not on the edge of this image. Maybe an aftereffect.

Comment: Have you tried my layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have a solution due to Golem's tip although it doesn't work with just one centered invisible item. I had to place invisible buttons left of "up", right of "up", left of "down" and in the center where one button has 100x100dp, the invisible side buttons have 80x80dp and the invisible center button has 60x60dp. If you know any better, let me know.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/controller_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_invisible_top_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control_invisible_side"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_invisible_top_left"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_up" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_invisible_top_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_up"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control_invisible_side"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_invisible_top_left"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_left" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_invisible_center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_left"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_up"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control_invisible_center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_invisible_center"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_invisible_top_right"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_up" />

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_invisible_bottom_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_left"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control_invisible_side"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_invisible" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_invisible_bottom_left"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_invisible_center"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button_invisible_bottom_left"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_down" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version (less Views), based on my original tip:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/controller_container"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_invisible_center"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="button_invisible"
        android:visibility="invisible"
    />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_left"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button_invisible_center"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/button_invisible_center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_left"
    />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_up"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_invisible_center"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button_invisible_center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_up"
    />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_right"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_invisible_center"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/button_invisible_center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_up"
    />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_down"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_invisible_center"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button_invisible_center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_control"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_down"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is:

[image]

I re-arranged the Views in order to minimize their count and therefore increase performances, being the layout lighter.

What was the trick? `wrap_content` in the container, shrunk everything to the center, whyle `match_parent` (which worked perfectly) was just out of specifics.

So I gave the buttons **fixed sizes** 80*80 dp and the container 3 times 80 dp (maximum combined width and height).

The image I used is't "cut out", so it better illustrates the concept.

Enjoy!

**[EDIT]**

In your case, this part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

is not needed. Just replace it with

```
<RelativeLayout
```

since it's meant to be placed inside another container.

Comment: I can't use "fixed" sizes, because my buttons don't grow exactly with the dependency (my buttons are always as big as a thumbnail, on all tablets and phones). I didn't try your concept now, but is it working because of your fixed sizes and how does it deal with the collapsing buttons I drawed? My invisible button is smaller than the other ones. What happens if your's is smaller too? How would the edgdes of the buttons be aligned? To the top edge of the invisible button or to the lower edge? I tried something similar first, but it didn't work because the alignment was always somehow wrong.

Comment: If the invidible button is smaller, than you risc that the other 4 buttons will overlap. For round (and transparent edged) images, this might be acceptable - until you reach a limit where they will overlap. The edges are aligned to the invisible button (i.e.: `android:layout_above="@id/button_invisible_center"` and `android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button_invisible_center"`). Now, I didn't try with `wrap_contents` **at run time**. Just saw it would be squashed in the **Graphical Editor** and fixed that. But not always what you see in the Graphical Editor is what you get at runtime.

Comment: I'm confident with my solution since it behaves as I want. But I upvoted your answer since it's also helpful.

Comment: And optimized, which is no little thing... ;)

Comment: You know, time is money. No time to tinker around a lot :)